# Pandas removing rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matrix

I'd like to remove a few rows in my csv file with pandas with that pivot table function. The format of the csv file looks like this:

```
ad dsdsa d adsadsa ewew
das ds dsd sad dsa dsa 
1 1 1.0 3
1 2 2.0 4
1 3 3.2 4
1 4 2.3 5
1 5 1.3 2
2 1 2.2 5
2 2 3.2 5
2 3 2.2 4
2 4 1.1 4
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
   1    2     3   4    5
1  1.0  2.0  3.2  2.3 1.3
2  2.2   5   3.2  1.1  . 
3   .    .     .   .   .
```

I have this which does the trick without the rubbish data in the first 2 rows:

```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv('third.csv', usecols=[0,1,2], names=['origin','destin', 'value'])
   pd.pivot_table(df, index='origin', columns='destin', values='value')
   pd.to.excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index='True')
```

As you can see, I used the first 3 columns, but I'd like to remove the first two rows in my csv file. Also, I'd like to export the new format to excel (but the last row of my code doesn't work).

Any thoughts to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

***demo***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """ad dsdsa d adsadsa ewew
das ds dsd sad dsa dsa 
1 1 1.0 3
1 2 2.0 4
1 3 3.2 4
1 4 2.3 5
1 5 1.3 2
2 1 2.2 5
2 2 3.2 5
2 3 2.2 4
2 4 1.1 4"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=2, header=None,
                 index_col=[0, 1], usecols=[0, 1, 2], squeeze=True)

df.unstack()
```

[image]

---

If the names on the indices bother you:

```
df.rename_axis([None, None]).unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good, however in my large CSV file, there is actually so many rows I'd like to remove and contains a lot of text, so most of the time I can't go on excel to just copy paste it into my code. Is there any other way such as skiprows=25?

Comment: if you know how many rows to skip, then yes use `skiprows=25`.  If you don't know how many rows to skip but each garbage line starts with something predictable, like a `'#'` then use the `comment` parameter.  Barring that, this becomes a completely different question.